# Setting JSLink SharePoint online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, list-view, jslink

Has anybody successfully set the JSLink for SP Online? I usually set it through Powershell on the view itself but that Command isn't available Online

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161388(v=office.15).aspx

I don't want to set the JSLink on a List View Web Part properties, it doesn't work. I've had this same problem with on-prem SP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since SharePoint 2013 supports [several sets of APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060%28v=office.15%29.aspx), you could *utilize client APIs (CSOM/REST) in PowerShell*.

### How to set View.JSlink property using PowerShell in SharePoint Online

**CSOM version**

The following example demonstrates  how to specify [View.JSlink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view.jslink(v=office.15).aspx) via CSOM in PowerShell:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-SPOCredentials([string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
   if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Password)) {
      $SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password" -AsSecureString 
   }
   else {
      $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
   }
   return New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
}

Function Configure-ListView([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [string]$ListTitle,[string]$ViewTitle)
{
    $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
    $view = $list.Views.GetByTitle($ViewTitle)
    $view.JSLink = "~sitecollection/SiteAssets/Tasks.js"
    $view.Update()
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

**Usage**

```
$UserName = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$WebUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com"


$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebUrl)
$Context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
Configure-ListView -Context $Context -ListTitle "Tasks" -ViewTitle "All Tasks"
$Context.Dispose()
```

It is also possible to accomplish using REST API, since this API could be consumed in PowerShell, follow [this article](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/04/15/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-powershell/) for a more details.