# Rename file from workflow in office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, rename

I need to rename a file when it is uploaded to a SharePoint online document library. As soon as document is uploaded, I will fill the metadata and then check in the file. For example, if the original file name is Test.docx, the changed file name will be Data_Date_Type.docx. I have tried using a workflow but it returns me a bad request.

I followed this link [How to rename a file using a SharePoint 2013 reusable workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158865/how-to-rename-a-file-using-a-sharepoint-2013-reusable-workflow)

But every time I update the document, the workflow shows bad request. I have fulfilled all the criteria for the REST headers but no luck! Any proactive suggestion is appreciated.

Please see the attachment I have tried using the REST call:

[image: Request Metadata]

[image: Request Parameters]

[image: Request Header]

As the workflow is giving Bad Request, I tried to update a different column - Title, and still the result is same.